# Open all the Platforms of ionic at one time with npm to preview app

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic2

When we run command `ionic serve` in cmd its gets open in browser and we can preview the platform selected in browser at mobile layout

My query is related to `ionic serve` is there any command to serve ionic the preview of all platforms i.e ios, android and windows get open at a time

..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `ionic serve --lab`

this command will open in android, windows and ios in a single window

Comment: yes correct you can also i found the solution `ionic serve -l`

Comment: ioinc serve -l is same as --lab